# How to assign different port number to different pages in php

Tags: php, port

I am trying to build a website on PHP. The site allows two type of user admin/sub-admin. Currently my site's dir structure is as follows:

```
MySite
  |-- admin     (contain all files/folders related to admin such as index.php, login.php)
  |--_img       (all image files)
  |--_jsStyle   (al jquery/css files)
  |
  (all sub-admin related files in MySite folder such as index.php,login.php)
```

When i accessed **localhost/MySite/** it opened the index page for sub-admin that leads to the login page for sub-admin and to open the login page for admin I have to use **localhost/MySite/admin/**.

Can I assign some port number to the admin folder so that instead of typing the folder name I use the port number to open the respective login pages, for example:

localhost/MySite:XXXX to open index page for sub-admin and

localhost/MySite:YYYYY to open index page for admin i.e. localhost/MySite/admin/

Comment: That would need to be set up on the web server level, that it has different vhosts listening to different ports etc. It would probably be a hassle to set up though. I honestly don't understand why you would want this though?

Comment: I want to hide the directory structure from the user. Because in future sub admin will also have different login authentication for different task, such as for MySite/updateinfo and MySite/selectinfo will have different credential for sub-admin. So I thought if there is a way in php to assign port number to folder to hide the directory structure or you can say folder name from the user. And to access different page user can use domain name and port number.

Comment: If you have a proper authentication/authorization layer in your application, it you wouldn't need this. As mentioned, this would need to be set up on the web server level as well as handled in your code. If you really want to, you can create a new vhost on your web server that listens to some port with a different document root, and just server it as a separate application. But I would rather have it set up as a sub domain in that case.

Comment: You need to either setup a separate http host inside your http server for each such "folder", including opening your firewall for all those ports and restarting the http server each time. Or you implement a socket client listening on all those ports, so implement your own http server, but that requires priviliges and certainly should _not_ be done in php.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, port number is placed after the domain name (i.e. `localhost` in your URLs), not the directory path.

PHP does not handle the TCP/IP level. It has no power in binding ports. You web server (e.g. Apache, Nginx, IIS)  binds port and route requests to the correct script file.

You can setup your web server to bind to different port than port 80. Then you can probably setup virtual host to different folder of your source code.

For example,

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/MySite"
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/MySite/admin"
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can go to http://localhost for the regular site. And http://localhost:8080 for the site within the admin folder.